# How do I call DismissViewController with a completionHandler?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Subject says it all. I want to wrap some code into the completionHandler of this method call. How do I do it?

code to wrap in the completion handler: vm.CancelDonationCommand.Execute(null);

```
this.DismissViewController(true,  ???);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the form that I discovered works for this situation.

```
this.DismissViewController(true, () => {  put commands here  });
```